# set condition for fetch array data

Tags: php

I have data from Oracle base and MS SQL base and I need to split them. One part data in Oracle base and another part on ms SQL. So I need to fetch data from MS SQL from date which i set. *P.S. all dates I have in bases and dates output ordered by DESC* and in total should be 12 rows. Here is my code:
*For example:*

### Oracle base data

12
11
10

---

### ms sql base data

**if Oracle stops on 10, so I should fetch data from 9**
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

```
   <?php
        $monthdifference = monthdif($mismonthnumb , Date("Y-m-d")); //this function to detect how many rows I should take data from oracle base
        $dovrArray = explode("|", $l_return);   // exploding data from oracle base

        for($i = 0; $i < $monthdifference; $i++){   //here i set row count 
            $xx = explode(",", $dovrArray[$i]);     //exploding again data from oracle
            $ss .= "<start>\n<example1>".$xx[0]."</example1>\n<example2>".(float)$xx[1]."</example2>\n<example3>".(float)$xx[2]."</example3>\n<example4>".$xx[3]."</example4>\n</start>\n";
        }
        $xml .= $ss;    //DONE FOR ORACLE BASE

        $connection = m_c("HERE IS MY CONNECTION BASE NAME");
        $popit =  getMonthString($code);    //Here i set date TILL which i should need to fetch data
        $query = "MY QUERY";
        $query_last_step = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query);   //ms sql query
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_last_step))
        {
            $ss .="<start>\n<example1>".$row [7]."</example1>\n<example2>".(float)$row [5]."</example2>\n<example3>".(float)$row [4]."</example3>\n<example4>".$row [3]."</example4>\n</start>\n";
        }
        $xml .= $ss;    //DONE FOR MS SQL BASE
    ?>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have procedure for ms sql and I should not change it. output of precedure is data with 12 month data(12 rows), i need to fetch data exactly from selected date. if oracle fetched 10 rows, so rest 2 rows i should fetch from ms sql.

Comment: Yes, but where are you meeting the wall, do you get any errors, what have you tried this far etc. Or did you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: i need help to write code which will work. if I write ` while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_last_step))
        {
if($row[7] == $popit)
            $ss .="....";
        }` it is not working, so i need help to wrote working code. How to write condition which will start fetching from column value which i set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, in case someone will need it.

I collect all to array

```html
<?php
$mssqlaray = array(); 
$index = 0; 
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{
  $mssqlaray[$index] = $row; 
  $index++; 
}
```

Than i just add it to for loop

```html
<?php
for($j = $monthdifference; $j < 12; $j++)
{
  $sss .="<start>\n<example1>".$mssqlaray[$j][7]."</example1>\n<example2>".(float)$mssqlaray[$j][5]."</example2>\n<example3>".(float)$mssqlaray[$j][4]."</example3>\n<example4>".$mssqlaray[$j][3]."</example4>\n</start>\n";
}
$xml .= $sss;
```

and split it to Oracle data